# check UNIQUE KEY in mysql level or do an if in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to know which one is better in this case for a mysql table with more than 1 million rows.

case 1:
select and check if data already exist in php level and if not insert a new data:

```
$stmt = $mysqli_link->prepare("SELECT * FROM likes WHERE post=? AND user=?");
$stmt->bind_param('is', $pinsid, $user);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$stmt->close();
$chknum = $result->num_rows;

if($chknum==0){
    $stmt = $mysqli_link->prepare("INSERT INTO likes (user, post) VALUES (?,?)"); ...}
```

case 2:
just use unique key in mysql

```
  UNIQUE KEY `unique` (`user`,`post`)
```

so, in other words, with one is faster? if I use first method, should I use second too?

Comment: You should never use method #1. Never. It's slower and worst of all - it can produce false results. The way we do this is create unique key and then just insert. If record exists,  you get an error (which we can interpret as an Exception and it's easy to deal with). If no error is returned, you've done the insert. That's not only the fastest way, but it's the **only** safe way to avoid duplicates. You get all the benefits using method #2 and 0 drawbacks. With method #1 you're simply screwed, without even knowing it.

Comment: thank you very much @N.B.! you completely answered my question!

Comment: @N.B. Can u plz elaborate how `Method #1` can return false result?

Comment: @Bsienn - there exists a small lag between PHP and MySQL. By the time you are finished querying and checking for existence of a record, another process could have added it (or removed it) and you have no way of defending against that. That's why integrity checks are not done in PHP (or any other language) and that's why we use unique constraints because the data authority is always the database - its job is to take care of data.

Comment: @N.B. Lesson learned. Thanks for explaining :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have a `PRIMARY KEY(user,post)`? If so, I would just use an `INSERT IGNORE`. That will be much faster than running the check yourself. Of course there is the question of why you have all this duplicate data. But that is beyond scope.

Answer (score 0):

Database doesn't care about 1 million rows. it will check with index key. The question is how u handle if duplicate key exists. That question will help u what approach to use.

One way is to test urself. calculate the time with each approach. with the following code. Decide ur self.

```
$start = microtime(true);
// code here
$time_elapsed_secs = microtime(true) - $start;
```